# Question about when the handler in $(document).ready(handler) gets called

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I know that the $(document).ready(handler) executes the handler when the DOM structure is loaded. But if you have a script that executes after you click a link and the script contains a $(document).ready(handler), will the handler get called? (like does the handler get called as long as the document is ready even if the document had completely loaded a long time ago? Also if you have jQuery that edits a DOM structure, does any handlers for any existing $(document).ready run again since the DOM structure will change and be ready again?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you ever have to use the $(document).ready handler in side of a click function.   If you are executing the click handler of an element then you can simply execute what is needed in the click handler itself with out calling $(document).ready.

Comment: yea that works but I was just curious as to what will happen to get a better understanding of the ready() in jQuery

Comment: Hi, I just thought I'd offer a quick tip: when you format your question, surround in-line code with backticks (`). It makes it more readable.

Comment: @John, when you have an ability to click a button it does not always mean that document is ready.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the handler will get called if the document is already ready. No, it doesn't get called again for changes in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Handlers bound with [`jQuery.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) will fire even if they are attached after the initial ready event is fired. *However*, handlers bound with [`jQuery.bind("ready")`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) will **not**. Potentially useful if you know, but could otherwise be confusing behaviour.

The events will not fire again when the DOM is manipulated.

Comment: Never knew they behave differently. But it's a little difficult to imagine a usefulness of the second case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're still getting the feel of jquery's execution. I would recommend popping some alert() calls in the different handlers during testing to get the hang of it. Like...

```
alert("This is first handler running.");
```